# How to use relative path in xaml of a Powershell

Tags: wpf, xaml, powershell

I have a powershell script reading a xaml file and displaying this.
When using an image in the xaml file like:

```
<Image Source="D:\Test\MyPic.png"  />
```

I have to provide the absolute path. Is there a syntax allowing to use relative path?
Hack solution: Read xaml and replace "D:\Test" with current module path in a dynamic way in the powershell script

Added example to clarify question:

```
Add-Type -assemblyName PresentationFramework, PresentationCore, WindowsBase

$syncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$newRunspace =[runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$newRunspace.ApartmentState = "STA"
$newRunspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"         
$newRunspace.Open()
$newRunspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("syncHash",$syncHash)          
$psCmd = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({   
    [xml]$xaml = @"
    <Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Name="Window" Title="Initial Window" WindowStartupLocation = "CenterScreen">
        <Image Source="D:\Test\MyPic.png" />
    </Window>
"@ 
    $reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
    $syncHash.Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )
    $syncHash.Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
})
$psCmd.Runspace = $newRunspace
$data = $psCmd.BeginInvoke()
```

Please note: The xaml is not embedded. Powershell reads it dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this, if the picture and script is in same folder:

```
$invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value
$directorypath = Split-Path $invocation.MyCommand.Path
$settingspath = $directorypath + '\MyPic.png'
<Image Source=$settingspath  />
```

Otherwise you can add 2 dots into path to get into previous folder like:

```
$settingspath = $directorypath + '\..\' + '\MyPic.png'
```

Comment: this exactly does not work. I guess because its in executes in a powershell.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. This is the workaround hack I try to avoid. I added a small example to clarify my question

Answer (score 1):

You can easy determine the script directory with a one-liner. Also consider to use the `Join-Path` cmdlet to combine your path:

```
$scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$myPicPath = Join-Path $scriptPath 'MyPic.png'
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. This is the workaround hack I try to avoid. I added a small example to clarify my question

Comment: You could also change the working dir (Set-Location) to the location of the script and then you can work with a relativ path. However, this would be a hack. The solution I provided is the cleanest IMHO.

Comment: NOP: If I change <Image Source="MyPic.png" /> 
and in AddScript add Set-Location 'D:\Test\' the image is not found

Comment: If you change the location before you use the png using `Set-Location (split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)` it will work (if MyPic.png is next to your powershell script)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the feedbacks.
I stick with the workaround like this:

```
$imgSplash = $syncHash.Window.FindName('imgSplash')
$splashUri = New-Object System.Uri $imgSplash.Source
$absolutPath = ("{0}\{1}" -f "D:\WhatEverPathNecessary,($splashUri.Segments | Select-Object -Last 1))
$imgSplash.Source = $absolutPath
```

This needs to be implemented before $syncHash.Window.ShowDialog()